# EntityFrameworkCore - Filter DbSet to a single property on another Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an `Account` entity, on which I want to have a `Subscription` property called `CurrentSubscription`.

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Subscription CurrentSubscription { get; set; }
}

public class Subscription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

In reality, there could be multiple `Subscription` rows for a given account but a business rule dictates that there will only ever be one (or none) with an `EndDate` of `null` (the `Account`'s current subscription). In my model I do not care about the others when I am retrieving an account as I am only after the *current* one.

How can I tell EF to do this? Playing around with the fluent API doesn't suggest there is anything built in on `PropertyBuilder` and every example of `HasDefaultValueSql` I have found has trivial `Sql` like `"GETDATE()"` as opposed to something parameterised, which this would need to be (`..where AccountId = ?`).

So I'm stuck.. any ideas?

Comment: "*How can I tell EF to do this?*" You can't. What you are describing is a *view* of the `Account` entity having collection of `Subscription`s. Hence cannot be mapped at entity level and should be modelled as view (DTO / ViewModel etc.) In general EF entity model represents the storage model, not business rule model.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Collection automatically loaded by EF
    public virtual List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

    // Returns Only (or none) subscription with null End date 
    public Subscription CurrentSubscription => Subscriptions.SingleOrDefault(r=>r.End == null);
}
```

`Account.Subscriptions`-collection is automatically (lazy) loaded by Entity Framework if foreign key is proper set on Subscription class (or by Fluent API):

```
public class Subscription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In reality, there could be multiple Subscription rows for a given account but a business rule dictates that there will only ever be one (or none) with an EndDate of null (the Account's current subscription). In my model I do not care about the others when I am retrieving an account as I am only after the current one. How can I tell EF to do this?

Entity Framework Core has exact solution that you are searching for and that is [EF Core Relationships : One-to-One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#one-to-one).

So your `Subscription` entity configuration should be as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>().HasOne(s => s.Account)
            .WithOne(a => a.CurrentSubscription).HasForeignKey<Subscription>(s => s.AccountId);
}
```

Moreover as there will be one or zero `Subscription` for `Account` so we can remove `Id` column from `Subscription` entity and make the `AccountId` as the primary key of the `Subscription` entity as follows:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `Subscription` entity configuration should be as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>(s =>
     {
        s.HasKey(sc => sc.AccountId); // <-- AccountId as primary key
        s.HasOne(sc => sc.Account).WithOne(a => a.CurrentSubscription)
                .HasForeignKey<Subscription>(sc => sc.AccountId);
     });
}
```